# What is the DFA for this NFA

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I am trying to convert this NFA to DFA. I tried to calculate the states for the following NFA, but the state table is growing more than 25 states. This will make my DFA sloppy and complicated. IS there any other way to convert the following NFA to DFA.The following is the part of long state table that I generated:

```
c   d   NULL
d   dh  d
e   NULL    f
f   NULL    g
g   g   gh
h   NULL    NULL
ab  abc ae
ae  ab  ef
dh  dh  d
gh  g   gh
abc abcd    ae
ef  NULL    ef
abcd    abcdh   aed
aed abdh    aefd
abcdh   abcdh   aed
abdh    abcdh   aed
aefd    abdh    aefgd
```

[NFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLvje.png)

[image]

Comment: Of course there is; it's a theorem. But the number of states in the associated DFA (at least the one generated systematically) will generally be quite large, as you've discovered. Consider looking at the proof in Sipser to see why.

Comment: Why do you care that the DFA is “sloppy and complicated?” It is what it is. The common algorithms for doing this conversion don’t usually produce a *minimal° DFA, though, so there’s a good chance that it can be “cleaned up” by one of the standard minimization algorithms.

Comment: **Hint**. The minimal DFA of your NFA has 15 states.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Maybe I have missed something? But it seems to me there is a simple DFA corresponding to the NFA(in the image) that has 11 states.